# Error:Failed to resolve: recyclerview-v7

Tags: java, android

when i add some dependency in my gradle and synced it set **Error:Failed to resolve: recyclerview-v7.**
i don't know what can i do.i research many time, but not solve.
i remove dependency but again error.

**below my dependency:**

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "avida.ican"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 2
        versionName "0.0.2"

        /*vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true*/
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
        implementation files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
        compile('com.stanfy:gson-xml-java:0.1.+') {
            exclude group: 'xmlpull', module: 'xmlpull' //xml to object
        }
        implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
        //________________________________________________
        //binding
        compile "com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1"
        annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1"
        //________________________________________________

        /*implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'*/

        implementation 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.11@aar'

        //loading
        implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'

        //change font
        implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'

        // reactive network  checked
        implementation 'com.github.pwittchen:reactivenetwork-rx2:0.12.3'

        //contain FileUtils and another utils
        implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'

        //contain FileUtils and another utils
        implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.11'

        //otto bus
        implementation 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'

        implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

        //FloatingActionButton
        implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'

        //editore for text
        implementation 'jp.wasabeef:richeditor-android:1.2.2'

        //ormlite use in project sqlite database
        implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:5.1'

        //file picker
        implementation 'com.github.angads25:filepicker:1.1.1'

        // recorder
        implementation 'com.github.adrielcafe:AndroidAudioRecorder:0.3.0'

        // image downloader
        implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'

        //multy image,video Picker with list croper
        implementation 'com.crop.multiple:multipleImagePickerLib:1.4.4'

        implementation  'com.booking:rtlviewpager:1.0.1'

        //--------------------------Tab----Layout--------------------
        implementation 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.6.1@aar'
           //Optional
        implementation 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:utils-v13:1.6.1@aar'
        //------------------------------------------------------------------

        //expandable TextView
        compile 'com.ms-square:expandableTextView:0.1.4'

    }
}
```

**below my project gradle:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.8.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            url 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I got tired please help me.

now my gradle dosnt sync.

i want add this dependency:
**compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'**

Comment: Me too facing the same problem. Got any solution?

Comment: no.no any one guid me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wooooooooow I finally resolved my problem.

i don't Know.but the problem was from maven **google()**.
i removed google() and add

```
 maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
```

Instead of.

i solve my problem from this [Link](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-react-native/issues/203)

this is my project gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/'
        }

        maven {
            url 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.8.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        //google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your thread man, my issue was related to yours :) You saved me posting on SO and hours oh searching haha :)

Answer (score 0):

U need this maven code in your project level gradle file :

```
repositories{
maven {
    url 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven'
}
```

}

Comment: i added tis but dos not work.you can see my project gradle